# gitlab 6.0：fatal: '/home/git/repositories/alex/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

Below is my configuration:

> config/gitlab.yml
> gitlab:
> host: 192.168.5.165
> port: 8001

config/database.yml

> username: gitlab
> password: "xxxxx"

gitlab-shell/config.yml:

`gitlab_url: "http://192.168.5.165:8001/"`

/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab:

> listen 192.168.5.165:8001;
>
> server_name 192.168.5.165;

when I creat a new project, and push from the command,I got errors:

> alex@ubuntu:~/gitlabProjects/test$ git remote add origin
> git@192.168.5.165:alex/test.git alex@ubuntu:~/gitlabProjects/test$ git
> push -u origin master fatal: '/home/git/repositories/alex/test.git'
> does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up
> unexpectedly

Then I tried another way ,I got the error：

> alex@ubuntu:~/gitlabProjects/test$ git remote add test
> git@192.168.5.165:8001:alex/test.git
> alex@ubuntu:~/gitlabProjects/test$ git push -u test master Access
> denied.

I am sure that my public key is ok. I really can not solve this problem.

> /home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check
> RAILS_ENV=production Checking Environment ...
>
> Git configured for git user? ... yes Has python2? ... yes python2 is
> supported version? ... yes
>
> Checking Environment ... Finished
>
> Checking GitLab Shell ...
>
> GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0) Repo base directory
> exists? ... yes Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no Repo base
> owned by git:git? ... yes Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
> post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes post-receive hooks in repos are
> links: ...  alex / write-clean-code ... ok alex / HelloGitlab ... ok
> alex / Test ... ok
>
> Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished
>
> Checking Sidekiq ...
>
> Running? ... yes
>
> Checking Sidekiq ... Finished
>
> Checking GitLab ...
>
> Database config exists? ... yes Database is SQLite ... no All
> migrations up? ... yes GitLab config exists? ... yes GitLab config
> outdated? ... no Log directory writable? ... yes Tmp directory
> writable? ... yes Init script exists? ... yes Init script up-to-date?
> ... yes Projects have satellites? ...  alex / write-clean-code ... yes
> alex / HelloGitlab ... yes alex / Test ... yes Redis version >= 2.0.0?
> ... yes Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git" Git version >= 1.7.10 ?
> ... yes (1.8.4)
>
> Checking GitLab ... Finished

Comment: Did you use the path that gitlab returns for that repository after creating it?

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I did use the url that the gitlab returned which was git@192.168.5.165:alex/test.git.

Comment: What do the checks say? Is sidekiq running?

Comment: All the items are green.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to do with your `Github` repository...

- First perform a cleanup by uncommitting your previous changes
- To reset your current `HEAD` to the specified state you can use following command, Try this

  `git reset --hard origin/master`